# iOS Sdk: UIImage Hue Cycle

Tags: ios, colors, uiimage, hue

I'm new to developing and I am trying to figure out how I could create a simple method to change an image HUE cyclically and programmatically. A sort of image effect that scan all the frequencies of the color spectrum, like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF2Xh-7vk4k) one, for example. I know I could create a set of images to animate this, but that would require memory space I don't want to waste. I know there is a way to create a loop cycle that allows me to scan all the colors of an image.

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

The [`CIHueAdjust` CoreImage filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) is available on iOS 5 and later. It should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you user1118321, i will try tu understand how to use it properly. :)